# Add values in xsl gave me wrong result

Tags: xml, xslt

I have very weird problem with adding two values in xsl.
XML:

```
 <BODY>
  <VALUE1>1.21</VALUE1>
  <VALUE2>1.22</VALUE2>
 </BODY>
```

XSL:

```
<sum><xsl:value-of select='BODY/VALUE1+BODY/VALUE2'/></sum>
```

Result:

```
<sum>2.4299999999999997</sum>
```

Why result is not 2.43 ? Maybe I should add in another way.

When VALUE1=1.31 and VALUE2=1.23 result is good.

Comment: Which processor?

Comment: Have you tried to add `1.21 + 1.22` in other programming languages having the same floating point double number representation (e.g. JavaScript)? The result will be the same. If you use an XSLT 2 or 3 processor you can use `xs:decimal` instead of the XPath 1.0 double type e.g. `BODY/VALUE1/xs:decimal(.) + BODY/VALUE2/xs:decimal(.)`. In any case, you can use `format-number where you want to output and format a computational result.